# Where is this file stored?

Tags: html, favicon

How do I locate a website's `favicon`? For example, where is the `favicon` located for [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: How is this a [programming question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the `favicon` for Stack Overflow is located at:

- http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico

To find:

1. [View the source of the page](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75129)
2. Search for `rel="shortcut icon"` and `rel="icon"`

   - If found, the following `href` attribute will contain the `favicon`'s location
   - If not, the `favicon`, if it exists, can be found at `DOMAINNAME.COM/favicon.ico`

Answer (score 2):

http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico